# Xamarin Forms: Customize Jump ListView Jump List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to customize the jump list on ListView? I know I can customize group headers with ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate. However I cannot find something like that for jump list. If not, is there a way to do it with custom renderer?

Regards

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same problem. Any updates on this...

Comment: No, I decided not to add them for the sake of time.

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi Did you got the answer

Comment: @AswathyKR : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737980/xamarin-vertical-alphabet-indexing-jump-list-for-grouped-list-in-xamarin-form

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls