# Xamarin: Vertical alphabet Indexing (Jump List) for grouped list in Xamarin forms for Android and windows UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have designed a grouped list view in Xamarin forms for ios,android and windows platform. The vertical indexing (Jump List) appears automatically in IOS when I set the GroupShortNameBindingproperty in my list view. But the jump list doesn't appear in android. How can I get the support of vertical indexing in android and windows also using custom rendering. If anyone can provide the source of custom rendering supporting this feature cross-platform.

[image]

Comment: Was there a solution that you ever came up with for this?

Comment: @FreakyAli It was long back, I haven't attempted it since then.

Comment: I will take that as a no i guess then?

Comment: @FreakyAli Sorry, I don't have any solution/resource to share for this :(

Comment: It's ok when i come up with a solution i will share it here as well

Comment: So i have a solution now you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289954/net-maui-jumplist-like-indexing-for-android-and-ios and https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls for it @HimanshuDwivedi

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to have XAML hack, if you don't want CustomRenders.

You can wrap your ListView in a RelativeLayout with height and width equal to the parent (content page).

For the list view use height as parent and width 90% of parent. 
Add a stack layout of width 10% and starting at 90% of the relative layout with height as parent. Make its orientation vertical. Add all the alphabets to the stack layout as Labels and implement its [TapGesture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/tap/) to [ScrollTo](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ScrollTo/p/System.Object/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollToPosition/System.Boolean/) the particular position.

Make the width 90% for Android only for iOS and windows keep it as 100%, stack layout width as 0% and `IsVisible=false`.

ViewModel :

```
public class JumpListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _allItems;
    private List<string> _alphabetList;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public JumpListViewModel()
    {
        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new List<Item> { new Item { MyText = "1" }, new Item { MyText = "2" }, new Item { MyText = "3" } });

        AlphabetList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems
    {
        get { return _allItems; }
        set
        {
            _allItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<string> AlphabetList
    {
        get { return _alphabetList; }
        set
        {
            _alphabetList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

View :

```
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
              SeparatorColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">
      <RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Constraint" Android="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=0.9}"
                    iOS="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1}"
          WinPhone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1}" />
      </RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint>

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Silver">

              <Label Text="{Binding MyText}" />
              <Button Text="button" />
              <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="Gray" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            </StackLayout>

          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AlphabetList}"
              SeparatorColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.9}"
      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.05}"
      RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.9}">
      <RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Constraint" Android="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=0.1}"
                    iOS="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=0, Constant=0}"
          WinPhone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=0, Constant=0}" />
      </RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint>
      <ListView.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" WinPhone="False" iOS="False" Android="True" />
      </ListView.IsVisible>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Micro" />
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot from Android :

[image]

Comment: do you have the sample now ?

Comment: @RohitVipinMathews can u share sample now?

Comment: Emulating the layout wasn't so hard but the big difference with iOS is the lack of touch & swipe, cos with Android you basically have to click on the little letters rather than just run thumb up and down. is there a solution short of writing a custom renderer?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls