# Xamarin.forms listview indexing

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.forms listview indexing both in android and iOS. Indexing has to be same in both (like iOS).

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin: Vertical alphabet Indexing (Jump List) for grouped list in Xamarin forms for Android and windows UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737980/xamarin-vertical-alphabet-indexing-jump-list-for-grouped-list-in-xamarin-form)

Comment: Is there anyway to show alpha indexer in listview for android?