# {Binding .} in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding

I saw this piece of code in an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737980/xamarin-vertical-alphabet-indexing-jump-list-for-grouped-list-in-xamarin-form) of some Xamarin code:

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#66ffff" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

What does Binding . mean? My guess from trying out the code is one character from the ItemsSource like in a regular expression? But I can't find this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics).

Comment: I think When we are using array of string and we want to bind that array into ListView at that time We don't have any property Name so we can use . for generalization.

Comment: `.` resolves to current `DataContext` of the control. If you want to know what is the current context of the control place a `TextBlock` and bind the `Text="{Binding .}"` property and it will show you what is the context. If you place the `Binding .` outside of the `ListView` you should see current ViewModel. If you place it inside of the `ItemTemplate` then yo will get current item from the collection that has been assigned as `DataContext`. _Note_ you can leave it empty as well. i.e. `Text="{Binding}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point (.) means that you bind the whole object/ model instead of a single property to the text property of that label. This is sometimes required, for example you need multiple aspects from your model in a converter.

In this code example above, it also could be that the item source for that listview is a list of strings. So there is no property to bind to the text property.