# Jump List on Android - how to achieve hold & swipe

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have been following this post in order to try and understand how Android can have similar functionality to iOS Jump List

[Xamarin: Vertical alphabet Indexing (Jump List) for grouped list in Xamarin forms for Android and windows UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737980/xamarin-vertical-alphabet-indexing-jump-list-for-grouped-list-in-xamarin-form/65737434#65737434)

I have had no problem implementing an alphabetical index using layouts, and furthermore implemented scrollto so when selecting a letter with tap, the main list will act accordingly

However, a key usability difference is that iOS, with the letters in the above example being so small, is designed to let user simply keep thumb depressed on screen and move up and down

With Android, because we're 'mimicking' this using ListView, you only have Tapped and Selected

Neither of these gives the same fluid experience as the user has to lift finger on and off screen

Is there a way to extend the list view on Android only so user can, just like iOS does out of box, slide up and down the alphabetical list and send events to the device to process?

```
                    ItemTapped="AlphaView_ItemTapped"
                    ItemSelected="AlphaView_ItemTapped"
```

Comment: If you are here because you are looking for something in Maui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77289954/net-maui-jumplist-like-indexing-for-android-and-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could custom **[ListViewRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview)** and [SetOnTouchListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.setontouchlistener?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Android.Views.View.SetOnTouchListener);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-MonoAndroid,Version%253Dv10.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) for listview, then can detect the hold & swip method.

For example, the sample renderer code as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace XamarinForms20.Droid
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
    {

        Context _context;

        public CustomListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        static float mPosX = 0, mPosY = 0, mCurPosX = 0, mCurPosY = 0;
        public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int viewheight = v.Height;
            switch (e.Action) {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    mPosX = e.GetX();
                    mPosY = e.GetY();
                    Console.WriteLine("Start on " + mPosY);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    mCurPosX = e.GetX();
                    mCurPosY = e.GetY();
                    Console.WriteLine("Now is moving " + mCurPosY);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                    if (mCurPosY - mPosY > 0
                            && (Math.Abs(mCurPosY - mPosY) > 25)) {
                        //scroll down
                        Console.WriteLine("scroll down to "+ mCurPosY/viewheight);
                    } else if (mCurPosY - mPosY< 0
                            && (Math.Abs(mCurPosY - mPosY) > 25)) {
                        //scroll up
                        Console.WriteLine("scroll up to " + mCurPosY/viewheight);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
    

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't be massively keen on implementing something 'obsolete' though

Comment: @Journeyman1234 I have updated code, the `obsolete` results form `ListViewRenderer`, you could solve it by tips from visual studio.

Comment: Yeah I figured what I'd do is read the latest 2021 documents on custom list view renderers in Android and see what's changed, then port your code in when got everything else working

Comment: @Journeyman1234 That's great. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: I have successfully implemented a touch listener by extending the ListView for Android, however as mentioned I needed to lead the latest documentation on how to extend it. A good source of reference for others would be https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ListView